# Python 2.7 pymongo can not update value with umlaut

Tags: python, encoding, pymongo

if i try update value that include umlaut characters (ñ) in mongodb with pymongo it throws

```
strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: "ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(ctextblob.cla...
```

i try encode manual:

```
        enc='UTF-8'  
        content = request.get_data() # raw encoded content
        u_content = content.decode(enc) # decodes from enc to unicode
        utf8_content = u_content.encode("UTF-8")
```

If i use instead enc='UTF-8'  other encoding it work but umlaut character is wrong. If i dont try decode and encode i get same exception

All code:

```
try:
    # Load params arriving as json data
    enc='UTF-8'  
    content = request.get_data() # raw encoded content
    print repr(content)
    u_content = content.decode(enc) # decodes from enc to unicode
    utf8_content = u_content.encode('UTF-8')
    params = json.loads(utf8_content)
    # Check all parameters
    customer_id = params.get('customer', '')
    check_credentials(customer_id, params.get('apikey', ''))
    collection_id = params.get('collection', '')
    if not collection_id or not str(collection_id).isdigit():
        raise Exception, "Invalid collection"
    train_records = params.get('train', [])    
    if not train_records:
        raise Exception, "Train records are needed in the 'train' parameter"
    # Store the trained classifier in database for a better performance
    train_records = map(lambda x: x.values(), train_records)
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train_records)
    pk = '%s__%i' % (customer_id, collection_id)
    data = {'_id': pk, 'customer': customer_id, 'collection': collection_id, 'classifier': pickle.dumps(cl), 'train':train_records}
    if db.classifiers.find_one({'_id': pk}):
        db.classifiers.update({'_id': pk}, data)
    else:
        db.classifiers.insert(data)
    print 'ok'
    # Asyncronously increase usage count in order to check rate limits
    gevent.spawn(increase_usage, customer_id)

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Here i have exception  `db.classifiers.update({'_id': pk}, data)`

after this line `params = json.loads(utf8_content)` ñ transform from \xc3\xb1 to u'\xf1'

Comment: Please add `print repr(content)` after the `get_data` line and tell us what it says.

Comment: '{\n  "apikey": "yt1uy23123123123",\n  "customer": 111111,\n  "collection": 111111,\n  "train": [\n    {\n      "text": "\xc3\xb1ww",\n      "label": "pos"\n    }\n  ]\n}'

Comment: "\xc3\xb1ww = ñww,  if i send simply ñ i get \xc3\xb1

Comment: That's strange - everything should work out of the box, without re-encoding. What happens if you remove it and do `params = json.loads(content)`?

Comment: i also try json.loads(request.get_data()) and result is the same

Comment: Could you add `print repr(data)` just before the `find_one` line?

Comment: i get this -         {'customer': 111111, 'train': [[u'\xf1', u'pos']], '_id': '111111__111111', 'classifier':  ....

Comment: I'm out of options, to be honest. Your data is fine, and I have no problems running your code. Are your mongo server and pymongo at the latest versions?